# importing CSV into FileMaker Pro 18 with CSV header line

Tags: csv, import, filemaker

Despite searching both Google and the documentation I can't figure this out:

I have a CSV file that has a header line, like this:

```
ID,Name,Street,City
1,John Doe,Main Street,Some City
2,Jane Done,Sideroad,Other City
```

Importing into FileMaker works well, except for two things:

1. It imports the header line as a data set, so I get one row that has an ID of "ID", a Name of "Name", etc.
2. It assigns the items to fields by order, including the default primary key, created date, etc. I have to manually re-assign them, which works but seems like work that could be avoided.

I would like it to understand that the header line is not a data set and that it could use the field names from the header line and match them to the field names in my FileMaker table.

How do I do that? Where is it explained?

Comment: I have posted an answer, but this type of question is much better suited to one of the forums dedicated to the Filemaker platform. There you can have a discussion and exchange files if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import records, you have the option to select a record in the source file that contains field names (usually the first row). See #4 [here](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help%2Fimport-action-field-mapping.html%23ww1083641).

Once you have done that, you will get the option to map the fields automatically by matching names.

If you're doing this periodically, it's best to script the action. A script will remember your choices, so you only need to do this once.

Comment: interesting. I saw that option, but it didn't make sense and wasn't explained anywhere. I will try it.

Comment: this is the right answer, plus the fact that when you select data, then in the top-right dropdown menu you can select "fitting names" and it will match the field names.

Comment: What’s the fm19 version of this answer. Amazing the interface would change so quickly.

Comment: @HenriettaMartingale I am not aware of any changes between v.18 and v.19 that would be relevant to this answer.

Comment: There is no use as field name option in fm19 as discussed in #4, at least that I can tell.

Comment: It's exactly the same. See #4 in v.19 help: https://help.claris.com/en/pro-help/content/import-action-field-mapping.html